# [error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '87'

Tags: deployment

I am new to `tfs-2018`, I am trying to do deploy on one of my servers but getting below error in the log. I was able to deploy on other 2 systems but one system is giving the bellow error. Any help will be appreciated

Log:

> 2018-01-29T06:55:20.8002862Z ##[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z ==============================================================================
>
> 2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z Task         : IIS Web App Manage
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z Description  : Create or update a Website, Web App, Virtual Directories, and Application Pool
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z Version      : 0.4.4
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839731)
>   2018-01-29T06:55:20.8484384Z ==============================================================================
>
> 2018-01-29T06:55:24.2725407Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list app "Default Web Site/PDM"
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.4872952Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/PDM" -[path='/'].physicalPath:"E:\inetpub\wwwroot\PDM" -[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].password:
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7066288Z APP object "Default Web Site/PDM" changed
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7066288Z ERROR ( hresult:80070057, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7998202Z 
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7998202Z The parameter is incorrect.
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7998202Z 
>   2018-01-29T06:55:24.7998202Z  )
>   2018-01-29T06:55:25.1905059Z ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '87'.
>   2018-01-29T06:55:25.3169881Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage

Below is the configuration details attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I too have a failure where `appcmd.exe` is returning status code 87 (via chef).

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue..?

Comment: I have some issues with code 4312, can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868189/azure-deploy-errorprocess-appcmd-exe-exited-with-code-4312

Answer (score 6):

I had similiar symptoms at one Windows Server 2012 R2 - on all other Windows Server 2012 R2 it would work.

### Symptoms

```
"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/foo" -applicationPool:"foo" -[path='/'].physicalPath:"C:\temp\foo" -[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].password:

ERROR ( hresult:80070057, message:Failed to commit configuration changes. 
The Parameter is incorrect.
)
```

We tried to figure out what was happening, and found that the `appcmd.exe` `password` Parameter would not work.

When omitting the `password` parameter the command would work fine:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/foo" -applicationPool:"foo" -[path='/'].physicalPath:"C:\temp\foo" -[path='/'].userName:
```

Another symptom that led us to the root of the problem was:

specifying `Physical Path credentials` for a `VirtualDirectory` via the mgmnt-console would also not work.

### Solution

For us, the problem was with a corrupt `IIS Configuration Key`. That prevented us from encrypting passwords in the `applicationhost.config`

We fixed the problem by importing the `IIS Configuration Key` from another test-machine.

*Reinstalling IIS would have worked as well* (if we ever had that problem on a production server)

**Exporting the config key from a working IIS Server**:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\temp\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -pri
```

**Importing the config key at the renitent IIS Server**:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\temp\iisConfigurationKey.xml"
```

**Replace AesProvider Element**

Finally we replaced the `AesProvider` Provider Element from `applicationHost.config`
 `configProtectedData` Section with the element from the working IIS Server and restarted the IIS.

Comment: You, sir, have saved my weekend! 

Comment: You sir, are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Buried in there you will see `The parameter is incorrect.` which is what Microsoft’s standardized error code 87 means.

In my case the list of urls was wrong (I wasn’t delimiting them correctly with colons, or the wildcards were incorrect). Looking at yours, I don’t see an equivalent field. But try simplifying the fields you have specified until you get something working, then add the real values back gradually.

Comment: appcmd.exe"  set app /app.name:"Default Web Site/PDM_Test" -[path='/'].physicalPath:"E:\inetpub\wwwroot" -[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].password:

it says
ERROR ( hresult:80070057, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.  
The parameter is incorrect.
Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '87'

Comment: Hmmmm, I’m not sure. Sorry I can’t figure it out, I’m not even a regular windows user anymore.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your effort, do you know anyone who in your thought can be able to resolve this or can give fare idea..you can mark him

thanks