# Azure Deploy [error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '4312'

Tags: azure, iis, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to do deploy on azure vm but getting below error in the log. Any help will be appreciated.

> 2019-02-25T14:02:55.2630391Z ##[section]Starting: Manage IISWebsite
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638264Z ==============================================================================
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638352Z Task         : IIS Web App Manage
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638426Z Description  : Create or update a Website, Web App, Virtual Directories, and Application Pool
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638480Z Version      : 0.5.9
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638542Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638599Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/iis-webapp-management-readme)
>   2019-02-25T14:02:55.2638661Z ==============================================================================
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.5249594Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list apppool /name:"azure2"
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.5894950Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set apppool /apppool.name:"azure2" -managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0 -managedPipelineMode:Integrated -processModel.identityType:ApplicationPoolIdentity
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.6765646Z APPPOOL object "azure2" changed
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.6880351Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list site /name:"azure2.desap.net"
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.7391199Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  add site /name:"azure2.desap.net" /physicalPath:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\net.desap.azure2"
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.8221558Z SITE object "azure2.desap.net" added
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.8254882Z APP object "azure2.desap.net/" added
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.8255141Z VDIR object "azure2.desap.net/" added
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.8450318Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"azure2.desap.net" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"azure2" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\net.desap.azure2" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.9132304Z SITE object "azure2.desap.net" changed
>   2019-02-25T14:02:56.9421865Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  list sites
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.0211736Z ##[command]"netsh" http show sslcert hostnameport=azure2.desap.net:443
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.0749939Z ##[command]"netsh" http add sslcert hostnameport=azure2.desap.net:443 certhash=*** appid={27113a38-e64f-45dd-8078-c551f0cd842e} certstorename=MY
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.1144820Z 
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.1145068Z SSL Certificate successfully added
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.1145124Z 
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.1319852Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set site /site.name:"azure2.desap.net" /bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:azure2.desap.net'].sslFlags:"1"
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.1773238Z ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.3415435Z ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '4312'.
>   2019-02-25T14:02:57.3731371Z ##[section]Finishing: Manage IISWebsite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error message was that there where no artifacts generated, I added this line at the end of my .yaml code and it got fixed.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error. Basically it didn't like changing the existing certificate attached to the site i.e. if your site's bindings in the IIS already had an existing certificate attached to it, which is different than your Release build; it will fail.

To correct it, I manually deleted (in order) the site and the Application Pool associated with it. And re ran the release, worked perfectly fine. Hope this helps someone.